# After deployment of vue app only homepage works, subpages not found

Tags: apache, vue.js, web-deployment

I have created a subdomain `test.example.com` from cPanel. I then built my Vue app using

```
npm run build
```

and zipped the whole **dist** folder to upload to the server. Once uploaded I expanded the zip file so the files are on the server.

This works perfectly for my home page, check, however, any of the subpages return the 404 while this issue is not observable on the localhost.

I don't understand how to fix this.

I use the `vue.config.js` with

```js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/'
}
```

and also the links to subpages look fine but just don’t work.

Comment: Could it be that your are using Vue-Router in history mode? If so, you need to configure your web server accordingly. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) in your router, in order for it to work all requests need to go back to index.html

> All you need to do is add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives in.

Since you are using cPanel I would assume that your server is using Apache.

Therefore you will need to create a `.htaccess` file to redirect all requests to `index.html`. You will need to create the `.htaccess` file inside your `public_html` folder (assuming that is where your application code lives). Then add the following.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling the server settings are missing but i did not know about the .htaccess! Works like a charm!